# If $f(z)$ is analytic function, and if real part of $f(z)$ is given then $f(z)=2u(\frac{z}{2}, \frac{z}{2i})-u(0,0)+iC$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have seen following theorem in my textbook. can any 1 pls give me hint on how to prove this?

> If $f(z)$ is analytic function, and if real part of $f(z)$ is given then $f(z)=2u(\frac{z}{2}, \frac{z}{2i})-u(0,0)+iC$, given that $f(z)=u+iv$

Comment: Can you precise what $u(\cdot, \cdot)$ is?

Comment: u is a function of (x,y); f(z)=u+iv

Comment: And what the two variables of $u$? I don’t understnd how it can be complexe variables.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net In textbook, he has given this statement directly to find f(z) given real part of f(z). I think it should have been derived from $x = \frac{z+\bar z}{2}, y = \frac {z=\bar z}{2i}$

Comment: I think the OP is implicitly using $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $z=x+iy$. This could certainly be wrong, it's just the associations I make while looking at it.

Comment: @Clayton. Probably... To the proposer : Do you mean that  $x=Re(z)$ and $y=Im(z)$ and $u=u(x,y)=Re(f(z))$? We are not psychic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we'll do is consider the function as power series.  Consider $u(x,y)$ as a power series of two variables around zero
$$
u(x,y) = \sum_{j,k=0}^\infty u_{jk} x^j y^k
$$
This converges uniformly and absolutely for $x$ and $y$ in an interval, so it will also converge uniformly absolutely for complex values of $x$ and $y$ in a whole disc around zero.  So you can feel free to plug in $x=\frac{z}{2}$ and $y=\frac{z}{2i}$ and it will work.  So how do you prove the formula?

This uses that you write $u$ as $\tilde{u}(z,\bar{z})$ (using tilde just for clarity, normally people just write this as $u$), that is you write $u$ as
a power series in both $z$ and $\bar{z}$.  This is just the above formula:
$$
\tilde{u}(z,\bar{z}) = u(\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2},\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i})
$$
What you then do is consider the function $\tilde{u}(z,\xi)$ (basically consider $\bar{z}$ as if it were independent.  This is sometimes called "complexification" or "polarization".

So suppose that $u$ is the real part of $f$, then this means that
$$
\tilde{u}(z,\bar{z}) =
\frac{f(z)-\overline{f(z)}}{2}
=
\frac{f(z)-\overline{f}(\bar{z})}{2}
$$
where by $\overline{f}$ we mean the power series of $f$ with all the coefficients barred.  Anyway, if this holds for all $z$, then it holds for
all $z$ and $\xi$, that is
$$
u(\frac{z+\xi}{2},\frac{z-\xi}{2i}) =
\tilde{u}(z,\xi) =
\frac{f(z)-\overline{f}(\xi)}{2}
$$
This follows from computing the series representation of each side, which only requires real derivatives in $x$ and $y$, meaning that the complex power series is the same.  Basically you need a result that says something like, if $h(z,\xi)$ is a convergent power series in two variables around 0 and $h(z,\bar{z})=0$ for all $z$ in a neighborhood of 0, then $h$ is identically zero.  See e.g. Proposition 3.1.5 in http://www.jirka.org/scv/scv.pdf .
Now it is just a matter of setting $\xi = 0$.

This is a very useful technique from several complex variables.